# How do you assign an action to a button in JScript?

Tags: javascript, html

just started learning Js for few days and i've been trying to make a button that when you click it, it would change the text of the 0 xp to 1, 2, 3,etc.. but im struggling to do so. Here is my code, any help would be appreciated.

```js
var have = document.getElementsByClassName("earn");
var credits = document.getElementsByClassName("money");
var button = document.getElementsById("singlebutton");


credits.onclick = change() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("money").innerHTML = "i++" + " xp";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Blank Page</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <form>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <p><button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success">Click here</button></p>
      </div>
      <div class="credit text-center">
        <div class="earn">
          <p>You have earned: </p>
        </div>
        <div class="money">0 xp</div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsById` is not a function ... `document.getElementById` is (note, Element vs Elements)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a (live) HTMLCollection - therefore it is not an element, therefore `onclick` is a meaningless property

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You just need this book https://www.nostarch.com/javascriptforkids. It's really cool to learn the basics

Comment: @divy3993 - not cool

Comment: credits.onclick = change() {//some code here} Does it really works ??. you have not used any "function" keyword before your function name

Comment: If u don't define type property of button it will by default be a submit button and will refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of typos

1. `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName`
2. `getElementById` not `getElementsById`
3. You can use `onclick` function for button
4. add type for button `type="button"`
5. Use index to get element from `getElementsByClassName`
6. Concatenation is wrong here  `"i++" + " xp";` it should be `(i++) + " xp";`
7. You have not declared `var i=0;`

```js
var i =0;
function change() {

document.getElementsByClassName("money")[0].innerHTML = (i++) + " xp";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

    <header>
        <h1>Blank Page</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <p><button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick ="change()">Click here</button></p>
            </div>

            <div class="credit text-center">
                <div class="earn"><p>You have earned: </p></div>
                <div class="money">0 xp</div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

append [0] after calls to document.getElementsByClassName everywhere like this to get the first element that matches

```
document.getElementsByClassName("earn")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have changed your code a bit.

Kudos to you for not mixing JS in your HTML code. I noticed there are some error in your code.

- JavaScript don't have `getElementsById()`, it has `getElementById()`.
- To attach an event to an element use
  `HTMLobject.addEventListener(eventname, myScript)`.
- Declare and
  initialise the variable `i`.

```js
var have = document.getElementsByClassName("earn");
var credits = document.getElementsByClassName("money");
var button = document.getElementById("singlebutton");
var i = 0;

button.addEventListener('click',function () {
    credits[0].innerHTML = (++i) + " xp";
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <p><button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success">Click here</button>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="credit text-center">
    <div class="earn"><p>You have earned: </p></div>
    <div class="money">0 xp</div>
</div>
```